# Importing the same component twice?

Tags: vuejs2

I use .vue files for my projects and normally have something like the below

```
<template>
My template code
</template>

<script>
import something from '../../somewhere';
import somethingelse from 'somewhereelse'
components: { something, somethingelse  },
...
</script>
```

If I was to use `something` in another .vue file, do I import it again, or just reference it?

I ask as I have just implemented the Quill Editor, imported it in my first file, but I forgot to import it on my second file, but it worked just by putting  tags in.

If I don't have to import into every file, should I actually be importing things at a higher level?

Comment: What is Quill Editor? A plugin? And how are you importing it?

Comment: https://github.com/surmon-china/vue-quill-editor

Exactly like the above, with an import statement

Comment: In the file you imported it in, did you add it to the `components` property? Or register it with `Vue.use()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a component in a Vue template if the component has been:

1. Defined in the current Vue instance
2. Imported from another file
3. Defined globally via a [Plugin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html)

Vue Plugins are different from components; they "usually add global level functionality to Vue".

The Quill Editor plugin seems to provide the `<quill-editor>` component at the global level for whichever Vue instance you use it with. That means that the Vue instance and its child components can use `<quill-editor>` in their templates without having to import anything.

I'm not sure what you are importing in your first file, but I don't think it is the `<quill-editor>` component.

Comment: Is there a way to find out when its global, I couldn't see anything. Im using webpack for compiling, will it strip out the double imports?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you importing it twice?

Comment: I had yes, but in two of my component files, imagine the code above in two separate files.

Comment: But your code in your example doesn't appear to be using a plugin, which is why I'm confused.

Comment: In one of my components I am using `components: { something }` but in another I can use the component without adding that or importing

Comment: but what is that `something`? The `quill-editor` component?

Comment: Something is just an example, but yes think of it as the Quill editor

Comment: Your second file shouldn't have access to it. Do you call `Vue.use()` anywhere in your code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142657/discussion-between-craig-ward-and-thanksd).